# how to find out which button was pressed last time python tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, interface

I have 4 buttons in a python interface with tkinter. 
I need to call a different function from every button.
So, I need to find out which button was last time pressed for calling a specific function.

Comment: Are you giving all the buttons the same `command` callback?

Comment: have you tried simply saving the command in a variable, and updating the variable each time it's called?

Comment: no, are different functions

Comment: If you have set the `command` option to different functions for different buttons, you have already done what you need.  Or do you mean you need to check which button was pressed before in those different functions?

Comment: i resolved, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can give an argument[specific to each button] to a function which will be called by button press event. In that function you will have to compare the given argument with button id to find out which was pressed. To get previous button pressed you will have to store that id in a variable.

```
pre_button_id = 0 ## variable to store previous button id
                  ## for future iterations

def test_function(button_id):
    global pre_button_id
    pre_button_id=button_id
    if button_id==1:
        ## call function 1 here
    elif button_id==2:
        ## call function 2 here
    elif button_id==3:
        ## call function 3 here
    elif button_id==4:
        ## call function 4 here


B1 = Button(root, text="1",command=lambda:test_function(1))
B2 = Button(root, text="2",command=lambda:test_function(2))
B3 = Button(root, text="3",command=lambda:test_function(3))
B4 = Button(root, text="4",command=lambda:test_function(4))
```